# pass array as parameter in an axios request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios

I need to make a request through **axios**, in which I want to pass as an array an array of this type `[1,2,3,4]`. I need this data to make a selection query from my backend, my question is: should I use a `GET` or `POST` request and what would be the correct way to pass this array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  can `POST` it as json data

```
let data=[1,2,3,4,5];
let json=JSON.stringify(data);
let post_data={json_data:json}
axios.post('/url',post_data)
```

- use  `JSON.stringify` to convert it to json string
- Use POST method to send data to server
- Use json_decode to convert json back to array on server side

On laravel side you can do like below

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($response,true);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, apparently everything is fine with my javascript code, but I have problems receiving the array in my laravel driver, apparently this did not work $ jsonArray = json_decode ($ response, true).

Comment: For best practices, the answer would depend on the purpose of your request, and you shouldn't use get/post interchangeably. Get requests should be idempotent, while post requests are not: 

https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html

Comment: I agree, using post is not good, I searched else where and found a decent answer using qs. I will link to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944387/how-to-correctly-use-axios-params-with-arrays

Comment: I however prefer not installing anything new and have moved to fetch:

const storeIds = [1,2,3]

const response = await fetch(`url/?${new URLSearchParams ({ storeIds }).toString()`)