# How to correctly use axios params with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios, http-get

How to add indexes to array in query string?

I tried send data like this:

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', { params: { storeIds: [1,2,3] })
```

And I got this url:

```
http://localhost/api/myController/myAction?storeIds[]=1&storeIds[]=2&storeIds[]=3
```

So, I should to get this url:

```
http://localhost/api/myController/myAction?storeIds[0]=1&storeIds[1]=2&storeIds[2]=3
```

What I should add in my params options to get this url?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - wouldn't the url with `[]` still work?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use `paramsSerializer` and serialize parameters with https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: {
    storeIds: [1,2,3]
  },
  paramsSerializer: params => {
    return qs.stringify(params)
  }
})
```

Comment: Helped a lot... Was quite stuck trying to figure out how to build the params myself.

Comment: Me too :D Thank you so much!

Comment: Even the axios documentation mentions the paramsSerializer just "by the way"

Comment: Note that by doing it, `params` become a `query`. So to access it in the back-end, you would have to write `req.query` instead of `req.params`. 
At least that was the case for myself.

Comment: It seems you can also use `querystring` Node module instead of qs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756756/axios-http-client-how-to-construct-http-post-url-with-form-params and https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/739

Comment: I got it to work using `qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: "repeat" })` instead of just `qs.stringify(params)` This answer helped too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153494/9195642

Comment: `qs.stringify(p, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})` helps me

Comment: Since 1.0.0 axios supports it natively, just set paramsSerializer.indexes to null. 
ref: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Answer (score 28):

Without having to add more libraries and using ES6 you could write:

```
axios.get(`/myController/myAction?${[1,2,3].map((n, index) => `storeIds[${index}]=${n}`).join('&')}`);
```

Comment: FYI, Axios is a library.  https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Oups! I meant MORE libraries. I corrected the answer, thanks!

Comment: I love this answer !. It's pure JS. No library required!.

Comment: to get this to work I did instead do

.map((n, index) => `storeIds[${index}]=${n}`).join('&')

otherwise since .map returns an array I have to do a join. Otherwise would get an unwanted ',' symbol between each value.

Comment: @PerHyyrynen you are right! I'll correct the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Thanks so much the answer from **Nicu Criste**, for my case, the API requires params like this:

```
params: {
  f: {
    key: 'abc',
    categories: ['a','b','c']
   },
  per_page: 10
}
```

Method is GET and this API requires the format is: `API?f[key]=abc&f[categories][]=a&f[categories][]=b...`
So I assigned the paramsSerializer of axios like this:

```
config.paramsSerializer = p => {
      return qs.stringify(p, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
    }
```

- Install `qs` please go to [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)
- Read more about paramsSerializer in [axios document](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)
- Edit format of params: Read more at [qs stringifying document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#stringifying)

Answer (score 16):

This behaviour has been added to `axios` starting with version `1.0.0`. See `paramsSerializer.indexes` at https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v1.0.0#request-config

Here's an example using your sample code:

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: { storeIds: [1,2,3] },
  paramsSerializer: {
    indexes: true, // use brackets with indexes
  }
)
```

The resulting query params will have indexes inside the brackets:

```
/myController/myAction?storeIds[0]=1&storeIds[1]=2&storeIds[2]=3
```

Other `paramsSerializer.indexes` values are `null` (no brackets):

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: { storeIds: [1,2,3] },
  paramsSerializer: {
    indexes: null, // no brackets at all
  }
)
// /myController/myAction?storeIds=1&storeIds=2&storeIds=3
```

And the default `false` (brackets without indexes):

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: { storeIds: [1,2,3] },
  paramsSerializer: {
    indexes: false, // brackets but no indexes
  }
)
// /myController/myAction?storeIds[]=1&storeIds[]=2&storeIds[]=3
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use ES6 array function. 
array element make querystring use reduce function.
Object array also works.

```
const storeIds = [1,2,3]
axios.get('some url', {
  params: {
    storeIds: storeIds.reduce((f, s) => `${f},${s}`)
  }
})
```

Comment: Your solution can be written a little shorter `storeIds.join(',')`

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers here. But I just wanted to share what I ended up using: (works like a charm even with other non-array parameters in your object)

Here is my params object:

```
params: {
    city: '335471',
    size: 4,
    page: 1,
    type: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
}
```

This is the axios get method:

```
$axios.get('/some/api/endpoint/', {
    params,
    paramsSerializer: (params) => parseParams(params),
})
```

```
function parseParams(params) {
  const keys = Object.keys(params)
  let options = ''

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    const isParamTypeObject = typeof params[key] === 'object'
    const isParamTypeArray = isParamTypeObject && params[key].length >= 0

    if (!isParamTypeObject) {
      options += `${key}=${params[key]}&`
    }

    if (isParamTypeObject && isParamTypeArray) {
      params[key].forEach((element) => {
        options += `${key}=${element}&`
      })
    }
  })

  return options ? options.slice(0, -1) : options
}
```

And finally, using this method you will send this request:

```
https://yourwebsite.com/api/some/api/endpoint/?city=335471&size=4&page=1&type=1&type=2&type=3&type=4&type=5&type=6
```

source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/604#issuecomment-420135579

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using someting like this

```
const params = array.map((v)=>{
            return `p=${v}&`
        })
```

Only concat `params.join('')` to the URL where you get data:

```
`url_to_get?${params.join('')`
```

In my back-end in ASP.net I receive this

```
[FromUri] string [] p
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the existing paramSerializer shipped in axios. The following snippet does the same serialization while putting indices between square brackets. I tried qs but it is not compatible with my python connexion backend (for JSON string parameters).

```
const rcg = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${url}/api`,
    paramsSerializer: params => {
        const parts = [];

        const encode = val => {
            return encodeURIComponent(val).replace(/%3A/gi, ':')
                .replace(/%24/g, '$')
                .replace(/%2C/gi, ',')
                .replace(/%20/g, '+')
                .replace(/%5B/gi, '[')
                .replace(/%5D/gi, ']');
        }

        const convertPart = (key, val) => {
            if (val instanceof Date)
                val = val.toISOString()
            else if (val instanceof Object)
                val = JSON.stringify(val)

            parts.push(encode(key) + '=' + encode(val));
        }

        Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if (val === null || typeof val === 'undefined')
                return

            if (Array.isArray(val))
                val.forEach((v, i) => convertPart(`${key}[${i}]`, v))
            else
                convertPart(key, val)
        })

        return parts.join('&')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by [@Nicu Criste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444749/7135309).

But might be not related to the posted question.

The following code was used to generate the query params with repetitive keys which had been supplied with an object array.

Note: If you are a developer with [bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/), use the following approach with care: as with [UrlSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) [support varies on different browsers and platforms](https://caniuse.com/?search=urlsearchparams).

```js
const queryParams = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}]

axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: queryParams,
  paramsSerializer: params => {
    return params.map((keyValuePair) => new URLSearchParams(keyValuePair)).join("&")
  }
})

// request -> /myController/myAction?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function as `parseParams` that can send the params to this function and serialize it.

```js
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
  params: {
    storeIds: [1,2,3]
  },
 paramsSerializer: params => parseParams(params)
})
```

parseParams function is;

```js
export const parseParams = (params) => {
  let options = '';

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      for (const element of value) {
        options += `${key}=${element}&`;
      }
    } else {
      options += `${key}=${value}&`;
    }
  }

  return options.slice(0, -1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got using "paramSerializer" a bit confuse. Before looking for the "right way" to use axios with array querystring on Google, I did following and got working:

```
var options = {};
var params = {};
for(var x=0;x<Products.length;x++){
   params[`VariableName[${x}]`] = Products[x].Id;
}
options.params = params;

axios.get(`https://someUrl/`, options)...
```

It is going to create querystring parameters like:

```
VariableName[0]=XPTO,VariableName[1]=XPTO2
```

which the most webservers expected as array format

Answer (score 0):

I know that this approach is not very good and I don't know the downsides it may have, but i tried this and it worked:

before making the request, prepare the params:

```
  let params = '?';

  for (let i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAY.length; i++) {  // In this case YOUR_ARRAY == [1, 2, 3]
    params += `storeIds=${YOUR_ARRAY[i]}`;  // storeIds is your PARAM_NAME
    if (i !== YOUR_ARRAY.length - 1) params += '&';
  }
```

And then make the request like so:

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction' + params)
```

Answer (score 0):

In React I needed to use axios with a params in array. This was query param:

`"fields[0]=username&fields[1]=id&populate[photo][fields][0]=url&populate[job][fields][1]=Job"`

to send with axios, for that I installed by CLI

`npm install qs` [Read more about qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying)

and declared

`const qs = require('qs');`

after
`const query = qs.stringify({`
       `fields: ['username', 'id'],`
       `populate: {`
           `photo: {`
               `fields: ['url']`
           `},`
           `job: {`
               `fields: ['Job']`
           `}`
       `}`
   `},  {`
`encodeValuesOnly: true`
`});`

and finally I called the axios like this:
`axios.create({`
  `baseURL: "http://localhost:1337/api/",`
`}).get(```/users?${query}```) // this parameter show all data`
       `.then((response) => console.log(response.data))`
       `.catch((err) => {`
           `setError(err);`
       `});`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, reading from docs https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config
`paramsSerializer` is an optional function, which we should use if the default serialization of `params` done by `axios` is not as expected. 
We can use serialization libraries (which I feel is best approach) to serialize in the params in the paramsSerializer function as per our needs.
Let's see an example.Suppose params is like ...

```
{
      params: {
        delay: 1,
        ar:[1,2,3]
      }
}
```

then you will get queryString like this `?delay=1&ar[]=1&ar[]=2&ar[]=3` when you make the request, but you might want like this
`?delay=1&ar[0]=1&ar[1]=2&ar[2]=3`
 so in order to get query string as per our format. we can use `qs` https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=qs library
 and serialize our params in the `paramsSerializer` function as below

```
{
      method: "GET",
      params: {
        delay: 1,
        ar:[1,2,3]
      },
      paramsSerializer: (params) => {
        return qs.stringify(params,{
          encodeValuesOnly: true
          });
      }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue that I wanted `axios` to omit brackets altogether. So I ended up with setting the `paramsSerializer.indexes` field to `null`. You can have the indices set as you want though by setting `indexes` to `true`.

```
axiosInstance.defaults.paramsSerializer = {  
  // e.g. instead of
  // storeIds[]=1&storeIds[]=2&storeIds[]=3 
  // you get
  // storeIds[0]=1&storeIds[1]=2&storeIds[2]=3 
  // with
  indexes: true
};
```

It can also be set per request as it is part of the `AxiosRequestConfig` interface:

```
axios.get(
  '/myController/myAction',
  { 
    params: { 
      storeIds: [1,2,3] 
    }, 
    paramsSerializer: {  
      indexes: true
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This work it for me:

```
axios.get("/financeiro/listar",{
        params: {
          periodo: this.filtro.periodo + "",
          mostrarApagados: this.filtro.mostrarApagados,
          mostrarPagos: this.filtro.mostrarPagos,
          categoria: this.filtro.categoria,
          conta: this.filtro.conta
        }
      })
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

This was better for me:

```
axios.get('/myController/myAction', {
params: { storeIds: [1,2,3] + ''}
```

})

Comment: That will not give the desired result.

Comment: It does not give exactly the expected result, but it works

Comment: It does **something** but you can't say it works if it doesn't do what the OP needs it to do.

Comment: Also please note that a solution that **does** do what is needed was found over a year ago and currently has a score of 18.

Comment: It is true. But it's always good to try to offer some better solution.

Comment: But it isn't better. It's a comma-separated string, which standard form data parsers will not separate for you, and which won't handle *data* with commas in this (this particular example only has digits so that isn't a problem in this specific case).

Comment: That's why I clarified that it was the best in my case. That worked for me, I think others could do something similar according to need

Comment: I tried both solutions and this one is the only one that works for me.  I use ids, It creates in the request the property `params: id1,id2,id3` and it works!!!

Comment: If you have full control of the server side API you are communicating with: then this is a VERY neat/terse way to get your required data up (from the client) using axios and a get request. It does not create a query string as the OP asked for, but it IS very simple, neat and efficient way to do some of what the OP was asking for i.e. for a Get request, using Axios: how do I put my "array in query string".

Comment: N.B. produces a url like : http://localhost/api/myController/myAction?storeIds=1,2,3

Comment: @Quentin is right that most server side frameworks by default will not parse this correctly, but N.B. we are talking GET request here. i.e. may well not be "form data" (_usually_ POST requests), and if you care about clarity and the number of bytes you're pushing up the wire this might be a good solution when coupled with some customisation on the server.

Answer (score -3):

In my case, there was already jQuery implemented into my codebase. So I just used the predefined method.

```
jQuery.param(Object)
```