# Axios and sequelize communication

Tags: vue.js, axios, sequelize.js

I experiment problems with an AXIOS GET query to my node sequelize back end .

```
axios.get("/api/employees", {
    "params": {
        "where": {
            "id": 2
        },
        "include": {
            "name": "offices"
        }
    }
}).then((response) => {
    this.employees = response.data;
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
});
```

My node web service doesn't accept this query in the findAll() function :

```
const readMany = (req, res) => {
     
        model.findAll(req.query)
            .then(function(dbModel) {
                res.json(dbModel);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                res.json(err);
            })
    };
```

I have been forced to write this ugly code, to make it work :

```
 const readMany = (req, res) => {
        // RECEIVING WHERE PARAMS
        if (req.query.where) {
            req.query.where = JSON.parse(req.query.where)
        }
        // RECEIVING INCLUDE PARAMS
        if (req.query.include) {
            var myobj = JSON.parse(req.query.include);
            var my_model = eval("models." + myobj.name)
        }
        // RECEIVING ORDER PARAMS
        if (req.query.order) {
            req.query.order = JSON.parse(req.query.order)
        }


        model.findAll({
                where: req.query.where,
                include: my_model,
                order:req.query.order
            })
            .then(function(dbModel) {
                res.json(dbModel);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                res.json(err);
            })
    };
```

Maybe you have a workaround ? Why do I have to convert to a JSON, and to separate like this ?
findAll() should accept an entire JSON object directly coming from Axios, no ?

Please have Look what a **console.log(req.body)** tells :

```
{ where: '{"id":2}' }
```

Please notice how much the quotes are weird, I can't even remove them  !

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved my answer using this post  :[How to correctly use axios params with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944387/how-to-correctly-use-axios-params-with-arrays)

This is how my Vue.js axios GET query looks now :

```
import qs from 'qs';

 axios.get("/api/employees", {
            "params": {
                attributes: ['lastName', 'firstName'],
                where:{id:2}
            },
            paramsSerializer: params => {
                return qs.stringify(params)
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            this.employees = response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
```

And how my SEQUELIZE node back end looks :

```
// =========
    // Read many
    // =========
    const readMany = (req, res) => {
  
        model.findAll(
                req.query
            )
            .then(function(dbModel) {
                res.json(dbModel);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                res.json(err);
            })
    };
```

Have a nice day, bro !

**Edit :** Still have an ugly code when doing jointures :

*My vue.js axios :*

```
  axios.get("/api/employees", {
                "params": {
                    where: {
                        id: 2
                    },
                    include: [{
                        model: "offices"
                    }]
                },
                paramsSerializer: params => {
                    return qs.stringify(params)
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                this.employees = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
            });
```

*My node server sequelize back end:* Ugly , but it works.

```
// =========
    // Read many
    // =========
    const readMany = (req, res) => {

        req.query.include[0].model = eval("models." + req.query.include[0].model)

        model.findAll(
                req.query
            )
            .then(function(dbModel) {
                res.json(dbModel);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                res.json(err);
            })
    };
```

I need this because models are generated by sequelize-auto , don't know how to do , it's ok like that. You can peep more demos on my github : nicolas15000