# Sending an array with axios.get as params is undefined

Tags: javascript, axios

I am making a get request with additional params options, since I am using that request on a filter, so the params are filters for what to get back:

```
const res = await axios.get("http://localhots:3000/getsomedata", {
  params: {
    firstFilter: someObject,
    secondFilter: [someOtherObject, someOtherObject]
  }
});
```

The request goes through just fine, on the other end, when I `console.log(req.query);` I see the following:

```
{
  firstFilter: 'someObject',
  'secondFilter[]': ['{someOtherObject}', '{someOtherObject}'],
}
```

If I do `req.query.firstFilter` that works just fine, but `req.query.secondFilter` does not work and in order for me to get the data, I have to do it with `req.query["secondFilter[]"]`, is there a way to avoid this and be able to get my array of data with `req.query.secondFilter`?

My workaround for now is to do:

```
const filter = {
  firstFilter: req.query.firstFilter,
  secondFilter: req.query["secondFilter[]"]
}
```

And it works of course, but I don't like it, I am for sure missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools for parsing query strings expect arrays of data to be encoded as `array_name=1&array_name=2`.

This could be a problem if you have one or more items because it might be an array or might be a string.

To avoid that problem PHP required arrays of data to be encoded as `array_name[]=1&array_name[]=2` and would discard all but the last item if you left the `[]` out (so you'd always get a string).

A lot of client libraries that generated data for submission over HTTP decided to do so in a way that was compatible with PHP (largely because PHP was and is very common).

So you need to either:

- Change the backend to be able to parse PHP style
- Change your call to axios so it doesn't generate PHP style

---

## Backend

The specifics depend what backend you are using, but it looks like you might be using Express.js.

See [the settings](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table).

You can turn on Extended (PHP-style) query parsing by setting it to "extended" (although that is the default)

```
const app = express()
app.set("query parser", "extended");
```

---

## Frontend

The [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) says:

> ```
>   // `paramsSerializer` is an optional function in charge of serializing `params`
>   // (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)
>   paramsSerializer: function (params) {
>     return Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
>   },
> ```

So you can override that

```
const res = await axios.get("http://localhots:3000/getsomedata", {
  params: {
    firstFilter: someObject,
    secondFilter: [someOtherObject, someOtherObject]
  },
  paramsSerializer: (params) => Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
});
```

My example requires the [qs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with params not being serialized correctly for HTTP GET method. Remember that GET has no "body" params similar to POST, it is a text URL.

For more information I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444749/15591475), which provides more detailed info with code snippets.