# Deserializing/parsing a 2d array (Axios/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm making a get request similar to this:

```
axios.get('https://example.org/getJobs', { params: { salaries, ... } }); // ... represents more params
```

where salaries is an array of arrays, or ranges, that I use to filter the jobs returned. I can access it fine on `req.query.salaries`, but it arrives on the server in the following format:

```
[ '["0","20000"]', '["20000","30000"]', '["30000","40000"]' ]
```

I'm just wondering what the best way to parse this is?

*Edit: Just to be clear, the array is originally sent in this format: `[['0', '20000'], ['20000', '30000'], ['30000', '40000']]`

`salaries` logged just before calling axios.get():

```
(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ['0', '20000']
1: (2) ['20000', '30000']
2: (2) ['30000', '40000']
3: (2) ['40000', '50000']
4: (2) ['50000', '60000']
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: send salaries as an array, is no need to send as array of json strings

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. How would I do that with an axios get request though? (I think it's axios that's serialising the array)

Comment: can you show the code which defines salaries?

Comment: Not easily, but I'm logging the salaries array just before the axios request, I'll add the log to the OP

Comment: ok, it might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944387/how-to-correctly-use-axios-params-with-arrays

Comment: something like `const onServerData = req.query.salaries.map(s=>JSON.parse(s))`

Comment: Lol. I swear blind I tried that @BabakKarimiAsl, it was even in one of my edits. I must have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks both of you

Comment: @NickW yeah it happens ;)