# Is there a way to serializeParams in axios without relying on a 3rd party library such as qs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, query-string

When using the [qs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) we control how arrays in query parameters would be with option `arrayFormat` (quote from `qs library` docs below):

> You may use the arrayFormat option to specify the format of the output array:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'indices' })
> // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
> // 'a[]=b&a[]=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' })
> // 'a=b&a=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })
> // 'a=b,c'
> ```

Is there a way to define this default array format in axios without having to import the qs library in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **paramsSerializer**.

For more information, you can see response and comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444749.

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly what I meant, I'm already using it. My ask is actually if there's a way to change the default serialization without having to pass a function that relies on the qs library. 
I will edit my question so this is more clear.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32515991)